# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic"

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

when I run npm run build, a folder is successfully generated on dist. but when I try to deploy to the server and try to run it in the browser, the following error appears:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

what does the error mean? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are trying to add some `script.js` to the `index.html` which has such import as `import {...} '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'`. This file should be compiled by the angular and it should be used inside of generated bundles. Normally, browser allows you to add imports, but it should be relative imports such as `import {a} from ./assets/script`. But if you still want to use named imports as `import {} from '@angular/core'`, use systemjs.